# Do not want to rollback all the successful transaction using batchupdate into jdbc template when got error in one batchupdate

Tags: java, spring, transactions, jdbctemplate, spring-transactions

I am having one issue where all successful transaction also gets rollback after successful commit using batchupdate in jdbc template.

Let's take an example : I want to commit first 3 batch after getting error in 4th batch. Currently its rollbacking all the transaction.

My expecting result is to commit successful 3 batches before got error in 4th batch.

Service.java

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void saveDataInBatch() {
    List<List<Address>> mainAddressList = getMainAddressList();
    for (int index = 0; index < 3; index++) {           addressRepository.saveWithBatchUpdate(mainAddressList.get(index));
        }
    }
```

AddressRepository.java

```
 @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
        public int[] saveWithBatchUpdate(List<Address> addressList) {
            return jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("insert into address (city,street, zipCode) values(?,?,?)",
                    new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
                    @Override
                    public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i){
                            Address address = addressList.get(i);
                            ps.setString(1, address.getCity());
                            ps.setString(2, address.getStreet());
                            ps.setInt(3, address.getZipCode());
                        }
    
                        @Override
                        public int getBatchSize() {
                            return addressList.size();
                        }
                    });
        }
```

Comment: Looks like you need to have separate transaction for each part of batch. then they will commit independently

Comment: @Anton Tokmakov, I am already having seperate transacfion using @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) for every batch.

Comment: Hi, Please share the relevant code. It is impossible to guess what's going on from the description only.

Comment: Hi, @Mar-Z please check above code

Comment: Please check again if correct code added. I can see the method called in service is saveSuccessBatch but the repository shows another method saveWithBatchUpdate.

Comment: @Mar-Z Code Corrected

Comment: You can try to use TransactionTemplate instead of annotations

Comment: @Anton Tokmakov, can we handle batch update with Transaction Template?

Comment: You can wrap ```addressRepository.saveWithBatchUpdate(mainAddressList.get(index)``` by transactionTemplate

Comment: Please remove the Transactional annotation from the service method saveDataInBatch. You should have only the method in repository annotated. Even with default propagation which is requires new.

Comment: @Anton Tokmakov, still getting same issue. you have any reference for this?

Comment: @Mar-Z but if i remove it then its working fine for error case but for success case it is not storing data into DB

Comment: Then it looks like you have turned the auto-commit off somewhere in the configuration. Either turn it on or you will need to commit manually at the (successful) end of the saveWithBatchUpdate method.

Comment: Is the issue solved now?

Comment: @Mar-Z No not yet